# Função só executa 1 vez

Tags: php, codeigniter, library

Criei uma `library` que redimensiona uma imagem que eu informo o nome, mas está acontecendo que preciso que a mesma imagem redimensione para 3 dimensões diferentes, então fiz o código

**imagem.php** (library)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Imagem{

    public function GerarImagem($imagem, $largura, $altura){

        $CI =& get_instance();

        $config = array();

        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = 'uploads/'.$imagem;
        $config['new_image'] = 'uploads/'.$altura.'x'.$largura.'_'.$imagem;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = true;
        $config['width'] = $largura;
        $config['quality'] = "100%";
        $config['height'] = $altura;

        $CI->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $CI->image_lib->resize();

        return $altura.'x'.$largura.'_'.$imagem;

    }

}
?>
```

E chamo ela no `model` assim:

```
$miniatura = $this->imagem->GerarImagem($foto_array['file_name'], 110, 110);
$media = $this->imagem->GerarImagem($foto_array['file_name'], 438, 438);
$grande = $this->imagem->GerarImagem($foto_array['file_name'], 720, 720);
```

O nome das imagens é inseridas certinhas no `MySQL`, só que ao fazer o redimensionamento ela só cria 1 imagem com a nova dimensão, que seria a primeira que chamei que foi a de **110x110**, o restante não cria na pasta.

Comment: Troque `$CI->image_lib->resize();` por `if ( ! $CI->image_lib->resize())
{
    echo $CI->image_lib->display_errors();
}` e me diga se aparece algo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento a primeira ele redimensiona de boa, mas as restantes ele retorna `Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image` . E são tudo jpg

Comment: Alisson sei que aqui não é lugar pra criticar tecnologias, mas pela mensagem de erro é um BUG, desculpe mas é um motivo que evito usar o CI, pode ser que eu esteja enganado, mas é o que me parece. De qualquer forma irei testar, me diga esta usando CI3?

Comment: Não, CI2.. Mas resolvi o problema, valeu!

Answer (score 0):

**Solução**

Troquei

```
$CI->load->library('image_lib', $config);
```

Por

```
$CI->load->library('image_lib');
$CI->image_lib->initialize($config)
```